# How to validate json with help of jsonschema?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I want to validate my json input -- `my_json`. I expected exception (because job1 is not job.

How to validate this json?

```
import json
from jsonschema import validate

# Describe what kind of json you expect.
schema = {
    "job" : {"type" : "string"},
    "big_list": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "qqq"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": ""
    }
    # many items
    ]
}

# Convert json to python object.
my_json = {'job1': "as", 'big_list': [{'id': 1, 'code': 'qqq'}, {'id': 2, 'code': ''}]}
validate(instance=my_json, schema=schema) # I expected exception, but have no exceptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the test correctly but the schema is wrong. Schema should be like this. You can check the json schema docs [here](https://json-schema.org)

```py
import json
from jsonschema import validate

# Describe what kind of json you expect.
schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : 
    {
        "job" : {"type" : "string"},
        "big_list" : {"type" : "object"},
     }
}

# Convert json to python object.
my_json = {'job1': "as", 'big_list': [{'id': 1, 'code': 'qqq'}, {'id': 2, 'code': ''}]}
valid_json = {'job1': "as", 'big_list': {'id': 1, 'code': 'qqq'}}
validate(instance=valid_json, schema=schema) # 
print('valid json has passed')
validate(instance=my_json, schema=schema) # this should raise an error
```

Comment: How can I specify one item of big_list? (e.g number of items may be different)

Comment: if you mean specifying the schema of item in big list,

Comment: you can check this example https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html

Comment: basically its an array of objects

Comment: I just found out that the code doesn't work. 
I expected only field "job", but "job1"  is accepted

Comment: Read the section on objects and how to prohibit additional properties.

Comment: if you want that to throw error, you need to put additionalProperties=false [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties) btw this has nothing to do with python code, its just the definition of json schema